# Склонение фамилии Дударенок

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте!
Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли мужская фамилия Дударенок?

Comment: @Ириша, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Да, склоняется.

Мужские фамилии на твердый согласный склоняются в обязательном порядке: Дударенок - Дударенку - Дударенком.

Answer (score 1):

То есть Карпук склоняется,
а Карпух нет? Фамилия редкая, но встречается. Как-то не катит, эту фамилию склоняют.
Скорее зависит это от малороссийского и русского толкования, у нас фамилию Гнедых склонять не получается, а в малороссии можно, Гнедому. Думается эти правила выдуманы. Натянуто, в силу непонятной причины, похоже от фонаря. А еще дело в том, что этимология многих фамилий непонятка страшная, поэтому просто не знают, как склонять, а обидеть можно невзначай.  Вот и не склоняют, абы впросак не попасть. На западе от этого ушли с упрощением, вообще перестали склонять, а может и не склоняли в силу ущербности?
А еще приемчик есть--присобачить чисто русское окончание типа-ов, нов, ин и пр., и все в порядке, склоняй на здоровье.

Answer (score 1):

Фамилия Карпух склоняется.

Карпух                     Карпух***ы***

Карпух***а***                  Карпух***ов***

Карпух***у***                 Карпух***ам***

Карпух***а***                 Карпух***ов***

Карпух                       Карпух***ами**
*

Карпух*е                  Карпух***ах***